# Batch Date Time breaks before 10am Windows 8

Tags: windows, date, csv, batch-file

Good day - would anyone be able to assist me with the below query.

Desired result i need would be a directory 25-08-2015-10-15 (dd/mm/yy-hh:mm)

Before 10 am i get a directory like 8-22(hh-mm) after 10 it writes :25-08-2015-10-15 (dd-mm-yy-hh-mm)

Below is my Batch File:

```
set dd=%DATE:~0,2%
set MM=%DATE:~3,2%
set yy=%DATE:~8,2%
set yyyy=%DATE:~6,4%
set hh=%TIME:~0,2%
set mm=%TIME:~3,2%

mkdir \Makereport\%folderdate%
set folderdate=%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,4%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%

mkdir \Makereport\%folderdate%

REM copy file to that date/Time
copy \Makereport\*.CSV \Makereport\%folderdate%\

cd %folderdate%
REM 7z.exe location

Path = c:\batch
7z a Retail.zip *.CSV -pRetailPass@
REM Subject Line for Email
mkdir \Makereport\%folderdate%\Retail_%folderdate%
cd..
del *.csv
```

I have tried to add:

```
if "%time:~0,1%" == " " (set folderdate=0%time:~1,1%) ELSE set folderdate=%time:~0,2%

echo folderdate=%date:~6%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%_%folderdate%%time:~3,2%
```

But I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: looks like your time settings are `h:m:s` and you need `hh:mm:ss`

Comment: to check your time settings run `reg query "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International"`

Comment: You should `echo` your `%TIME%` and check the difference for both times

Comment: Hi Npocmaka 
The desired result works fine after 10am (dd/mm/yy/hh/mm)  before then i only get (hh/mm) - just at my original post (edited)

Comment: Take a look at [How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/203116/3074564) how to get current date and time string with wmic command independent on language settings in a format you want.

Comment: Thanks Guys - Ill have a look at all the points made - Many Thanks Npocmaka & Jeb

Comment: Thanks Mofi - i missed that page

Comment: Hi Guys
I added
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)

For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%b-%%a)

Answer (score 0):

Add the lower line - I think it should fix an issue where a space is at the start of the time before 10am.

Other solutions exist but this may be the one you are after.

```
set hh=%TIME:~0,2%
set hh=%hh: =0%
```